# How to make username and age first 3 characters of his name then age?

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication

**I want it here**

A Student comes and registers his account, his name is Sammy and his age is 16 I want to program like automatically it will pick his **first 3** letter of his name and then his **age** After creating an account his username should not be Sammy it should be **sam16** First 3 letter and then age.
Please Help

> First 3 Letter **Jhonny**
>   
>   His Age **12**
>   
>   Final Look **jho12**

## Register

```
def register():
    while True:
        username = input("New username: ")
        if not len(username) > 1:
            print("Username should be more than 2 characters")
            continue
        else:
            break
        print("")
    while True:
        password = input("New password: ")
        if not len(password) > 3:
            print("Password should be more than 5 characters, " + username )
            continue
        else:
            break
        print("")
    while True:
        age = input("Enter Your age: ")
        if not len(age) > 0:
            print("Age can't be blank, " + username )
            continue
        else:
            break
        print("")
    print("Creating account...")
    users[username] = {}
    users[username]["password"] = password
    users[username]["group"] = "user"
    time.sleep(2)
    print("")
    print("Account has been created, " + username)
```

Comment: `username[:3]+str(age)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Where will it show your username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
name = 'John Soe'
age = 32
username = name[:3] + str(age)
print(username)
```

Output:

> Joh32

In your case you can so like this:

```
def register():
    while True:
        username = input("New username: ")
        if not len(username) > 1:
            print("Username should be more than 2 characters")
            continue
        else:
            break
        print("")
    while True:
        password = input("New password: ")
        if not len(password) > 3:
            print("Password should be more than 5 characters, " + username )
            continue
        else:
            break
        print("")
    while True:
        age = input("Enter Your age: ")
        if not len(age) > 0:
            print("Age can't be blank, " + username )
            continue
        else:
            break
        print("")
    print("Creating account...")
    username = username[:3] + str(age)
    users[username] = {}
    users[username]["password"] = password
    users[username]["group"] = "user"
    time.sleep(2)
    print("")
    print("Account has been created, " + username)
```

Comment: I'm trying to add this part in my code but it's not working please can u add this part in the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
username = username[:3].lower()+str(age)
```